# how to integrate visa to website?

Tags: php, integrate

I want to integrate "visa" to my website (developed in PHP), so other people can make a deposit to my website.

I don't know how to do it, are there any examples or documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Create an account on Paypal, and let them do the work. These days very few people will trust their credit card number to "just anyone". Not only will this get your "trust", but all the overhead of managing these things will be taken care of for you, with minimal overhead for you. They will give you code to embed on your page "Donate Now" - they handle the rest.

Did I mention trust?

Comment: But they give you very clear instructions... Based on the quality of the question, I think this is the best approach for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

- it depends on your bank,
  you should contact them and they will provide you their API , 
  -if you use CMS for your site there ready extensions on joomla for example,
  -you have also the choice to integrate paypal API on your website

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the US you could also use [stripe](http://www.stripe.com). The api is very easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Just updating, VISA has a resource for developers and special offers to independent developers. Just go to their [hotsite](https://developer.visa.com)